# MySQL: duplicating data for more performance?

Tags: mysql

I have a big table (200'000'000 rows); declared like this

```
 thread( forum_id tinyint, thread_id int, 
         date_first datetime, date_last datetime
         replycount mediumint, extra blob )
```

forum_id and thread_id are the primary key. With big forums (around a million of topics) i sometimes have to run queries like `SELECT thread_id FROM thread ORDER BY date_last DESC LIMIT 500000, 10`. These queries with huge offsets takes a second or maybe a few to run.

So i tought that i could, by duplicating data, create a few tables for the forums with most threads to speed this up. Only a few forums are over 100'000 topics, so there will be a table like

```
  thread_for_forumid_123456 ( thread_id int, 
         date_first datetime, date_last datetime
         replycount mediumint )
```

What do you think about this? Will it speed up huge offset queries? Do you have some other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to run the query with such a high offset? Or is it just for testing purpose?

Comment: performancy? performancy? what is that awful non-word!!!!!

Comment: Instead of duplicating the data, create a view?

Comment: It's not just a test, it's a real world app! Sorry for my awful English. Will check for this "view", thanks.

Comment: In what real world (forum-)app would you need to pull 4999990 entries from a Database?

Comment: Ops. I want to get 10 rows, starting from 500000... Sorry I confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, i will *REALLY* try to avoid your approach. I look at it as the "last chance" to avoid performance issues.

You have alternatives (from hardware to software) on hard you can buy Fusion i/o or just an SSD drive ([Raid vs SSD vs FusionIO](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/01/raid-vs-ssd-vs-fusionio/)). But, you can solve this using software and dont investing money at all.
On your scenario you should use cache (i.e. [memcached](http://memcached.org/)) if you aren't already using it.
[MySQL have partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html), its not the best choice in the world but, you can have some good performance increase.

BUT, if you go with your idea, i suggest that you *shard* your data, using a value that split your data across tables more *balanced*.
You can do something nasty like: create 50 tables like thread_0 to thread_49 
And then (forumid % 50) so you land on one of this 50 tables.
That way you avoid to create a table everytime you create a forum, and you avoid to have N tables. And the select with forum_id indexed will be very fast.
Also **you can have some sort of logic on the app to manage pagination, and avoid huge offsets**.

Good luck!

PS: I add a blogpost on MysqlPerfomanceBlog ["Why you dont want to shard"](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/08/06/why-you-dont-want-to-shard/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is the large offset `LIMIT 500000, 10`.

I don't see why you have 5'000'000 here. If you filter for the thread_id and forum_id the offset should be very small because I do not belive you have 5 million post in one thread.

```
SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE thread_id = 123456 ORDER BY date_last DESC LIMIT 10, 50
```

Maybe also have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: That query doesn't make any sense to me. Why should I select the thread id of a know thread id?

Comment: How do you plan to call `thread_for_forumid_123456(...)` without thread_id?

Comment: 123456 is the forumid. In a table like that I will have several threadids, that I will order by date and return... I think that I didn't understand your answer, sorry.

Comment: I rewrote my answer. Maybe it is better to understand now.

Comment: It's not about posts here... Anyway, are you saying that if I restrict the search like what I'm already doing (forumid =, threadid =, MySQL will act like if the other fields dosemt exist, in the offset time performance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html) sound like a functionality you may consider